# More than one object on a UML state machine?

Tags: uml

How do you represent more than one object on a UML state machine, or would that not make sense at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the objects are supposed to be running in parallel, you can use orthogonal regions to model them, a region for an object.

Answer (score 0):

What do you means with objects? in a State Machine you can have stats and transitions.

Answer (score 0):

If more than object should execute the state machine make the machine a method of the object.